sAMAccountName is not included in the access token in SSO with OIDC of AzureEntraID and AWS ALB
I created an SSO environment using OIDC using Azure EntraID and AWS ALB.
Even though groups(sAMAccountName) is included in the token configuration on the EntraID side,
When I look at the access to the backend after SSO sign-in, groups is not included in the access token in the header.
I get access token from header ('x-amzn-oidc-accesstoken').
Also, "x-amzn-oidc-data" has different contents, but it also does not include groups.
If I use cognito and SAML for authentication, I can get groups. However, because it is a private environment, cognito cannot be used in my region, so I have no choice but to use OIDC authentication with ALB. (AWS, Azure, and on-premises servers are connected via a dedicated line)
Also, ALB does not support SAML.
Oddly enough, no matter how I added groups and other optional items to the complaint request, the access token remained the same.
In addition, the group is included in the ID token that is displayed in the browser URL when accessing the endpoint (/oauth2/v2.0/authorize). I would like to know if there is a way to obtain this token on the backend side.
This ID token will appear in the redirected browser URL when I enter the following URL in my browser: An error screen is displayed because the redirect destination is an ALB authentication endpoint.
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/(tenant_id)/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=…
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=https://(ALB DNS)/oauth2/idpresponse
&scope=openid
&state=…
&nonce=…


The reason why groups is necessary is because we want to change the backend processing depending on the group.
